# Get rid of the space between an inline-block and an inline element

Tags: css, html-table, css-tables

As a potential solution to [CSS3: inline TABLE TD columns, but keep it aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450200/css3-inline-table-td-columns-but-keep-it-aligned), I have the following CSS, but it has two issues:

1. The `</td><td>` without the space and `</td> <td>` with the space get interpreted differently, with the latter having an extra space when rendered, causing misalignment between the two.
2. In addition to the above, `justify`ing the text causes an extra variation in alignment between the different `</td> <td>` lines, depending on how much padding each space on the line gets.

How do I remove this extra space with CSS, or, at the very least, make it appear consistently even with the `justify`?

```css
table {text-align: justify; width: 4em; font-size: 32pt;}

td:nth-child(1) {display: inline-block; min-width: 2em;}

td:nth-child(2) {display: inline;}

/*tr {text-align: left;}*/
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>d d f s d x z</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>dd f sdxz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>ddf sdxz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td> <td>d d f s d x z</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td> <td>dd f sdxz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td> <td>ddf sdxz</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Apparently, this only appears to be reproducible in Mozilla, not in WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can set 0 size to font in tr, than space between td will have 0 size too. You can write something like that.

```css
table {text-align: justify; width: 4em; font-size: 32pt;}

tr {font-size: 0;}

td {font-size: 32pt;}

td:nth-child(1) {display: inline-block; min-width: 2em;}

td:nth-child(2) {display: inline;}

/*tr {text-align: left;}*/
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>d d f s d x z</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>dd f sdxz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>ddf sdxz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td> <td>d d f s d x z</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td> <td>dd f sdxz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td> <td>ddf sdxz</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work properly, perhaps because the width of the table ends up being set incorrectly due to `em` being based on font-size

Comment: actually, even if we change `em` to `pt`, it still looks like there are implicit spaces that get in the way, and continue to mess up the alignment at least in mozilla

Comment: I fixed table. Can you check now?

Comment: no, as I said, in mozilla, it still suffers from some sort of implicit spacing taking up the space w/ justify.